# What design pattern is best suitable with this context?

Tags: design, design-patterns

I have a base class Shape, and drived classes Line Segment, Arc, B-spline,... I want to find the intersection point between these shapes. I would like:

```
Shape* a = new LineSegment();
Shape* b = new Arc();

bool did_intersect = a->Intersect(b);
```

I don't like this design in Intersect:

```
bool LineSegment(Shape* s) {
  Arc* arc = dynamic_cast<Arc*>(s);
  if (NULL != arc)
    return LineSegmentArcIntersection(this, arc);

  BSpline* bspline = dynamic_cast<BSpline*>(s);
  if (NULL != bspline)
    return LineSegmentBSplineIntersection(this, bspline);
  ...
}
```

So, What **design pattern** is best suitable with this context?

Comment: Why don't you like *this* design?

Comment: I think this design violate Open-Closed Principle. This structure is repeated over all drived classes.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) or [multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch).

Btw., this question is better suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: Effective C++ by Scott Meyers has a great article on `double dispatch` talking at great detail on how to implement it also!

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425993/making-entity-class-closed-for-changes ?